# Run a jmeter thread group every 5 minutes

Tags: loops, jmeter, threadgroup

My jmeter test plan has a thread group that has a csv config and 2 HTTP requests

I want to be able to run the thread group every 5 minutes so it performs a csv config and 2 HTTP requests every 5 minutes

Google search hasn't gave me much info

Thanks for any suggestion

Barry

UPDATE:  For the benefit of others

To solve my problem I uses the Test Action Sampler, as follows:

```
Send first HTTP Request
Send second HTTP Request
Test Action Sampler - Wait 5 minutes in milliseconds
```

I put this in a thread group that loops forever and it sends the 2 requests every 5 minutes

Answer (score 4):

Does your Thread Group contain single HTTP request? Well, add [Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers) to the the Thread Group.

Comment: Thanks for the info and yes it contains a couple of HTTP requests  I updated original post